Flutter goto previous GNav tab from Button
i am using GNav in my application i have implemented to change GNav tab on click of button
Flutter change GNav tab from Button
this helped me,
This is my GNav
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_couriers/constants/colors/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:food_couriers/screens/cart_screen/cart_screen.dart';
import 'package:food_couriers/screens/chat_screen/chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:food_couriers/screens/home_screen/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:food_couriers/screens/profile_screen/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';

class BottomNavigationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomNavigationScreen> createState() => _BottomNavigationScreenState();
}

class _BottomNavigationScreenState extends State<BottomNavigationScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: [
          HomeScreen(
            onTapProfile: () {
              _onItemTapped(1);
            },
          ),
          ProfileScreen(
            onTapBack: () {},
          ),
          const CartScreen(),
          const ChatScreen(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 15,
          horizontal: 21,
        ),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(22),
            topRight: Radius.circular(22),
          ),
        ),
        child: GNav(
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTabChange: _onItemTapped,
          backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
          tabBackgroundColor: AppColors.secondary,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 17,
            vertical: 10,
          ),
              tabBorderRadius: 12,
          gap: 13,
          iconSize: 30,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            height: 15.72 / 12,
          ),
          tabs: const [
            GButton(
              icon: Icons.home,
              iconActiveColor: AppColors.primary,
              iconColor: AppColors.secondary,
              text: 'Home',
            ),
            GButton(
              icon: Icons.person,
              iconActiveColor: AppColors.primary,
              iconColor: AppColors.secondary,
              text: 'Profile',
            ),
            GButton(
              icon: Icons.shopping_cart,
              iconActiveColor: AppColors.primary,
              iconColor: AppColors.secondary,
              text: 'Cart',
            ),
            GButton(
              icon: Icons.chat,
              iconActiveColor: AppColors.primary,
              iconColor: AppColors.secondary,
              text: 'Chat',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is my ProfileScreen
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_couriers/constants/images/images.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.onTapBack,
  });

  final VoidCallback onTapBack;

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Image.asset(
              Images.profilePattern,
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

i have to question one is that how do i hide GNav when i am on ProfileScreen and the other question is that when i click on back button on ProfileScreen it will go back to previously selected GNav tab
I want to hide Gnav on ProfileScreen and go back to previously selected tab.
